# Is it possible to remove/hide the open button from IFileDialog

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, dialog

I am trying to use the IFileOpenDialog to pick both files and folders (in multi-select mode) from the same dialog. I was able to add a custom button to the dialog and achieve what i want to do. Now i want to remove the default "Open" button from the dialog because its behavior is dependent on the order of selection. If a file is selected first and then a folder (multiselect), I get the OnFileOk event but if a user selects a folder first then a file, a click on the open button opens the first selected folder. Is there a way to remove or hide the Open button ??

My idea was to enumerate the child windows of IFileDialog and remove the child with caption "Open" and class "Button". I tried enumerating the child windows of IFileOpenDialog before doing the show, but I get only one child with class "Button" but its caption is "start". I cannot find a standard way of hiding the "Open" button. Please let me know if there is any other way of doing this.

Thanks,
Abhinay.

Comment: Sounds to me you found the Windows Start button, clearly you got the wrong window handle.  Do take a look at IFileDialogCustomize::RemoveControlItem().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Buke's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389833/bukes) [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8733474/18437) worked for me but you have to wait until the dialog controls are created. It seems like every time the dialog is created [`OnFolderChange()`](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=onfolderchange&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=QnYKT9H3K4iimQX9hqCdAg&usg=AFQjCNGsje0Sipxgeu0WJY7p4BH5tq2Raw) is called so I just added my hiding code there:

```
STDMETHODIMP FileDialogEventHandler::OnFolderChange(IFileDialog* fileDialog) {    
    IOleWindow *pWindow = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = fileDialog->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pWindow));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        HWND hwndDialog;
        hr = pWindow->GetWindow(&hwndDialog);    
        HWND openButton = GetDlgItem(hwndDialog, IDOK);
        ShowWindow(openButton, SW_HIDE);

        pWindow->Release();
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the dialog item number (You can find the button ID using Spyxx), you may be able to do something like this:

```
HWND hOpenButton = GetDlgItem( hDlg, itemID );
ShowWindow( hOpwnButton, SW_HIDE );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IFileDialogCustomize::RemoveControlItem
```